# apache virtual hosting on a private ip

Tags: apache, ubuntu, virtualhost

I have successfully configured 2 virtual host sites (Name based virtual hosting) on ubuntu. My apache version is 2.2.22.
Both sites works on localhost.

/etc/hosts entries

```
127.0.0.1 www.abc.com 
127.0.0.1 www.xyz.com
```

ports.conf content

```
NameVirtualHost *:80 
Listen 80
```

apache2.conf content

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.abc.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/abc
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.xyz.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/xyz
</VirtualHost>
```

How can I set the domain names to 10.1.2.1 www.abc.com and configure the apache server ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `/etc/hosts` files is used for local mappings of hostnames, but will not make your Ubuntu machine an outward facing web server. I suggest you remove those, so you will be able to better test the following steps.

First, you may need to modify `/etc/network/interfaces` and ensure your server is using your static IP (presumably `10.1.2.1`). Additionally, ensure your DNS provider is routing the domains `www.abc.com` and `www.xyz.com` to this IP address.

Then if the apache server is started (`service apache2 start`), it will listen on port 80, and respond to any web requests with the contents of `DocumentRoot` as specified in the configuration file above.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.